Azure policy to disable defender for storage on resources (resource level) with the selected tag
I'm trying to build a custom azure policy that disables Azure Defender for storage on resources (resource level) with the selected tag but having some issues to make it work or to even to determine if it can work.
here is a sample azure policy that I used but the policies are not working as expected in that if a resource becomes compliant (i.e. defender for storage is disable manually), the policy keeps auditing the resource as being non compliant, and the reason for non compliance is as follows
Reason for non-compliance
No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code: Bad Request)
Existence condition
Type
Microsoft.Security/defenderForStorageSettings
Policy definition:
"policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "in": [
            "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          ]
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('inclusionTagName'), ']')]",
          "in": "[parameters('inclusionTagValues')]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "name": "storageAccounts",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
        ],
        "existenceCondition": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Security/pricings/pricingTier",
          "equals": "Free"
        },
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "parameters": {
              "fullResourceName": {
                "value": "[field('id')]"
              }
            },
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "fullResourceName": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "variables": {},
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
                  "apiVersion": "2024-01-01",
                  "scope": "[parameters('fullResourceName')]",
                  "name": "storageAccounts",
                  "properties": {
                    "pricingTier": "Free"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "outputs": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

Another policy definition:
policyRule: {
      if: {
        allOf: [
          {
            field: 'type'
            equals: 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
          }
          {
            field: 'tags[dfs-enabled]'
            equals: 'off'
          }
        ]
      }
      then: {
        effect: 'auditIfNotExists'
        details: {
          type: 'Microsoft.Security/pricings'
          name: 'storageAccounts'
          existenceCondition: {
            field: 'Microsoft.Security/defenderForStorageSettings/isEnabled'
            equals: true
          }
        }`

"deployment":....


Azure policy to disable defender for storage on resources (resource level) with the selected tag]

As there is a built-in policy for enabling Microsoft Defender for Storage named Configure Microsoft Defender for Storage to be enabled here, you can just change the policy to disable.
Here is the policy to disable Microsoft Defender for Storage
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['DefenderEnabled']",
          "equals": "True"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "name": "StorageAccounts",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fb1c8493-542b-48eb-b624-b4c8fea62acd"
        ],
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/pricings/pricingTier",
              "equals": "Standard"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/pricings/subPlan",
              "equals": "[parameters('subPlan')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "parameters": {
              "subPlan": {
                "value": "[parameters('subPlan')]"
              }
            },
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "subPlan": {
                  "type": "String"
                }
              },
              "variables": {},
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
                  "apiVersion": "2023-01-01",
                  "name": "StorageAccounts",
                  "properties": {
                    "subPlan": "[parameters('subPlan')]",
                    "pricingTier": "Standard",
                    "extensions": [
                      {
                        "name": "OnUploadMalwareScanning",
                        "isEnabled": "False"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "SensitiveDataDiscovery",
                        "isEnabled": "False"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "outputs": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "DeployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
    },
    "subPlan": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Storage bundle's sub plan",
        "description": "Sets the sub plan for Storage bundle"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "PerTransaction",
        "PerStorageAccount",
        "DefenderForStorageV2"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DefenderForStorageV2"
    }
  }
}

Make sure to enable the remediation task while assigning the policy to disable Microsoft Defender for Storage.

Alternatively, You can also disable the Microsoft defender for storage accounts on specific tag using PowerShell Script .
To disable Microsoft Defender for storage accounts based on a specific tag, you can use an automation runbook by following the Stack link.

Note: Make sure to assign Security Admin role to identity to disable the defender.

    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        if ($storageAccount.Tags["Environment"] -eq "Production") {
            Disable-AzSecurityAdvancedThreatProtection -ResourceId $storageAccount.Id
            Write-Host "Advanced Threat Protection disabled for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        } else {
            Write-Host "Storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName) does not match the tag condition."
        }
    }

Output:

